How do I pass prop "title" to svgr react component properly?
I need to pass prop title to react component which returns svg tag.
My webpack @svgr/webpack loader settings:
    {
        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
        options: { memo: true, titleProp: true }  // <= titleProp: true allows to pass prop "title" to svgr react component
    }

My type declaration of svg:
declare module '*.svg' {
    import { type FC, type SVGProps } from 'react'
    const SVG: FC<SVGProps<SVGElement>>
    export default SVG
}

My component code:
<HomeIcon title='Home' />  // <= mistake says that there is no 'title' property

Problem is that there is no title property which you can pass as prop.
According to svg declaration const SVG: FC<SVGProps<SVGElement>>, it leads to that interface:
interface SVGProps<T> extends SVGAttributes<T>, ClassAttributes<T> {}

and if we check interface SVGAttributes<T>, it doesn't have prop title inside. If I write prop title manually in interface SVGAttributes<T>, it works correctly.
Seems strange, but I don't think I need to do it manually. All interfaces are from @types/react: "^18.3.12"
So how to do it properly? Do I need to use other declaration for .svg?

Found a solution.
interface SVGAttributes<T> doesn't need to have title prop, becuase when title prop is passed, @svgr/webpack creates a tag <title> inside <svg> tag, not put title as an attribute.
So all we need is to make proper declaration through intersection to avoid mistake which says that title prop doesn't exist:
declare module '*.svg' {
    import { type FC, type SVGProps } from 'react'
    const SVG: FC<SVGProps<SVGElement> & { title?: string }>
    export default SVG
}

